# Firestore multi whereFilter query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
let query = firebase.firestore().collection('rooms')
query = query.where('location', '==', 'CA')
query = query.where('range', '>', '10')
query = query.where('range', '<', '1000')
const res = yield query.get()
```

I can't get response from this query. If I remove either range filter or location filter, this query runs well. How can I get res from the above query?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a query like yours, a warning like this is displayed in your IDE:

> W/Firestore: (19.0.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(rooms where location == CA and range < 1000 and range > 10 order by range, *location*) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/...

So that query will not work unless you create an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) for it. This can be done, by creating it manually in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) or you can simply click on that link or copy and paste the url into a web broswer and you index will be created automatically.